# Android Background Service and Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background

I am developing android application using rabbit mq pub/sub technology. I want to listen incoming message in android background service. Can I run thread in android background service ?

```
public class MessagingService extends Service {

private Thread subscribeThread;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    subscribeThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Connecting to server and listen incoming message.
        }
    });
    subscribeThread.start();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    subscribeThread.interrupt();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can run new thread in Android Service.

Please see note in documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work.

Hope this will help you.